# Write Python Dataframe into a Word/Excel Document with Specific Formatting

Tags: python, excel, pandas, conditional-formatting

Hi I'm relatively new to python and was hoping if any of you guys can provide advice on templating matters.

I've managed to parse an excel file, made a dataframe out of the data (using xl.parse, .loc, str.contains, str.split, sort_index etc. methods) and output it into another excel file like so:
[Excel doc with dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhA82.png)

I'm stuck at formatting - adding borders, bolding certain rows of strings (not necessarily in the same position between 2 different output files), highlighting certain cells with color, etc.

I have a template which I have to follow, like so(word doc): [Format to replicate (word doc)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7b8B.png)

I'm considering two ways about this:

1) Replicate the formatting from scratch through python (either as an excel or word doc)

2) Write the raw data from the output excel file to the word doc with the template

It'd be great if someone can enlighten me on which way is more efficient, and what libraries, methods/functions I can look into to get the job done.

Thank you!

Comment: A nice example of how to format to excel can be found in the [Practical Business Python](http://pbpython.com/improve-pandas-excel-output.html) blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [`xlsxwriter`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/). You can add borders with code like this:

```
import xlsxwriter

# left
begcol = 2 # skip first col
endcol = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
begrow = 2 # skip first row
endrow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

ws.Range(ws.Cells(begrow, begcol), 
         ws.Cells(endrow, endcol)).Borders(7).LineStyle = 1 # continuous
ws.Range(ws.Cells(begrow, begcol), 
         ws.Cells(endrow, endcol)).Borders(7).Weight = 2 # thin
```

You can bold a row this way:

```
# bold last row
ws.Range(ws.Cells(endrow, begcol),
         ws.Cells(endrow, endcol)).Font.Bold = True
```

You can set the background color of a cell like this:

```
format = workbook.add_format()

format.set_pattern(1)  # This is optional when using a solid fill.
format.set_bg_color('green')

worksheet.write('A1', 'Ray', format)
```

For writing to Word Documents you can use [`docx`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with an example of how to do that here: http://pbpython.com/python-word-template.html

Answer (score 1):

There are a few good ways to do this. I typically do one of the following two approaches:

1) [XLSX writer](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial02.html): This package has support for changing formatting of Excel files. So my workflow would be to export to Excel using Pandas in Python then after the data is in the Excel file I'd manipulate the formatting with XLSX. Pandas and XLSX Writer play well together as you can see from [this demo](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html).

2) For some workflows I found the amount/type of formatting I wanted to do in Excel was just not reasonable to do with XLSX Writer. In those cases the best bet is to put your data in something that's NOT Excel then link Excel to it. One easy approach is dumping the data to a CSV then linking your well formated Excel file to the CSV. You could also push data into a database with Pandas and then have the Excel file pull data from the DB.